# want to develop a app in python which interacts with the web and posts on facebook , twitter and gtalk?

Tags: python

i want to develop a python desktop app which interacts and posts its content on facebook , twitter or gtalk as a message . is it possible?... tutorials and ideas will help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Twitter API](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/) will help you for Twitter, since it's intended to help you post messages.  The Facebook API isn't actually what you want - it helps you write applications which run on Facebook, but doesn't necessarily help you communicate with Facebook the way that a user would.  To do that you might need to look at how Facebook communicates with a browser - using something like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) and [Live HTTP Headers](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/) and then replicating the browser behaviour using [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html)/[urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) (there is an excellent tutorial [here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml)).  For gtalk, the underlying implementation is [Jabber/XMPP](http://www.jabber.org/) for which you should be able to find plenty of documentation (there's even a [book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596521271/) published by O'Reilly).

Comment: can i implement it all in the same code and run all the process at the same time?

Answer (score 3):

If you can't find a facebook API to suit your needs, you'll have to make one from scratch. Try using the [Charles web debugging proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to surf around facebook and post comments, add friends etc. It will reveal and log all the headers and GET/POST traffic. You can use the logged requests and responses to engineer your own API. It'll be a pain, but its a good exercise. If you get stuck, just post a query on this website. The issues are all common enough that people post solutions within a few minutes.

A few pointers:

- Facebook requires a login, meaning you'll probably need to build your own urlopener using a cookie handler from cookielib. You'll also have to get comfortable programming HTTP POST requests.
- Facebook probably won't tolerate traffic from automated scripts, so all your traffic with the website will have to emulate a browser--slowish request rates, and a strategically defined "user-agent" element in the HTTP request headers.

Answer (score 2):

You can check out APIs of [Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/), [Twitter](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/) and [Gtalk](http://code.google.com/apis/talk/)

Comment: i did , but they are for developing apps for integrating facebook app inside facebook environment . i dont want that

Comment: Then make a thin application in facebook that provides Interface to your python dektop app.

Comment: You can include it in your application .. http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/API